# get unique slug in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, slug

I want to get unique slug for my articles. I am using codeigniter. I was wondering to have some thing like `sample-title-1` and `sample-title-2` if there are two articles that have the same title like codeignier does with file upload `filename(:num)` . I could not figure out a way to do it. I am not an expert on codeigniter. I am learning it.

I prepared a function, when passed a string `$str` it checks if the slug exists, if it does, it adds the `ID` of that article to the end of that slug and returns it, if not, it returns the slug.

It is working fine and serving the purpose of unique slug. But what I wanted was to have something like `sample-title-1` and `sample-title-2` . Is there any way to do so?

```
$data['slug'] = $this->get_slug($data['title']);


public function get_slug ($str)
    {
        $slug = url_title($str, 'dash', true);
        // Do NOT validate if slug already exists
        // UNLESS it's the slug for the current page

        $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
        ! $id || $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
        $category = $this->category_m->get();

        if (count($category)) {
            return $slug.$id;
        }

        return $slug;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using slugs in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305786/using-slugs-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

easy to use and really helpful to create unique slugs have look on [CI slug library](https://github.com/ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Slug-Library)

read its documentation to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

what i used to do is to make `slug db field UNIQUE`.

Then easly do all with the CI helpers [Url Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) and [Text Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html)

```
    $last_id_inserted = //get from db the last post's ID;
    $post_title = "My slug would be";
    $slug =  mb_strtolower(url_title(convert_accented_characters($post_title))).'-'.$last_id_inserted;
    echo $slug;
    //outputting my-slug-would-be-123



//insert the new post with slug
```

So ID will be unique and slug too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like that:

```
//Database loaded
//Text helper loaded

function post_uniq_slug($slug, $separator='-', $increment_number_at_end=FALSE) {    
    //check if the last char is a number
    //that could break this script if we don't handle it
    $last_char_is_number = is_numeric($slug[strlen($slug)-1]);
    //add a point to this slug if needed to prevent number collision..
    $slug = $slug. ($last_char_is_number && $increment_number_at_end? '.':'');

    //if slug exists already, increment it
    $i=0;
    $limit = 20; //for security reason
    while( get_instance()->db->where('slug', $slug)->count_all_results('posts') != 0) {
        //increment the slug
        $slug = increment_string($slug, $separator);

        if($i > $limit) {
            //break;
            return FALSE;
        }

        $i++;
    }

    //so now we have unique slug
    //remove the dot create because number collision
    if($last_char_is_number && $increment_number_at_end) $slug = str_replace('.','', $slug);

    return $slug;
}
```

Examples:

```
post_uniq_slug('sample'); //"sample" exists
//sample-1

post_uniq_slug('sample-2013'); //"sample-2013" exists
//sample-2013-2

post_uniq_slug('sample-2013', '-', TRUE); //increment "sample-2013"
//sample-2014
```

*NOT TESTED

Answer (score 0):

```
public function create_slug($name)
{
 $table='tradeshow';    //Write table name
 $field='slug';         //Write field name
 $slug = $name;  //Write title for slug
 $slug = url_title($name);
 $key=NULL;
 $value=NULL;       
 $i = 0;
 $params = array ();
 $params[$field] = $slug;

if($key)$params["$key !="] = $value;

while ($this->db->from($table)->where($params)->get()->num_rows())
    {  
        if (!preg_match ('/-{1}[0-9]+$/', $slug ))
        $slug .= '-' . ++$i;
        else
        $slug = preg_replace ('/[0-9]+$/', ++$i, $slug );
        $params [$field] = $slug;
    }  

    return $alias=$slug;}
```