# how to redirect page using href tag in ci?

Tags: codeigniter

controller:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Test extends CI_Controller 
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            parent :: __construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->model('Fetch_data');
        }
        public function college()
        {
            $college_name = $this->input->get('college_name');
            $this->load->view('college');
        }
    }
```

view:

```
<ul class="list">
<?php
    foreach ($engineering_priority as $row)
    {
        echo "<li><a href='test/college/".$row['college_name']."(".$row['field'].")' id='coll'>" . $row['college_name'] . "</a></li>";   
    }
?>
</ul>
```

I am new in ci. In view I have create a link and want to redirect into controller/view/college_name i.e (test/college/abc college). So, How can I do this ? please help me.

Thank You

Comment: what is the output for now? and please clarify the problem more.

Answer (score 1):

First off all you must configure your base_url in the

`application/config/config.php`

then you can edit the

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_site_folder/';`

after finished configuring this you can use the `base_url()` for your urls.

example:

you want to make a link to go on your controller `test` and function `college` you do it like this:

```
<ul class="list">
 <?php foreach ($engineering_priority as $row) { ?>
    <li>
       <a href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/college'>
           <?php echo $row['college_name'];?>
       </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

You can try it this way.

Comment: From \comment above base_url URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL, WITH a trailing slash: `/`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add `/` at the end of the base_url link on my config.php but I updated it now. Thanks

Comment: @NelsonEstuestaJr my link is http://localhost/collegescan_ci/index.php/test/college/Annai%20Mira%20College%20of%20Engineering%20and%20Technology,%20Vellore(engineering). when I click on a link it give me error The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: have you added `http://` on the start of your link? just like this; `http://localhost/collegescan_ci/index.php/test/college/`

Comment: can I see the controller with that function `college`?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `base Url` in `config.php`

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>test/college/<?php echo $row['college_name'].$row['field']; ?>"><?php echo $row['college_name'] ?></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to set the base url in `application/config/config.php`.

then you can use your link as 

`echo "<li><a href='" . base_url() . "test/college/".$row['college_name']."(".$row['field'].")' id='coll'>" . $row['college_name'] . "</a></li>";`

Also in your code you have the parameter `$row['college_name']."(".$row['field']` which is the parameter to the `college()` function so you can get that parameter as

```
public function college($college_name_from_link)
    {
        //get data of college 
        //$this->data['college'] = query for data 
        $college_name = $college_name_from_link;
        $this->load->view('college', $this->data);// generate view with passing $this->data['college'] array to view
    }
```

Comment: I have test/college/Annai%20Mira%20College%20of%20Engineering%20and%20Technology%20Vellore(engineering) in my url and it showing error An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: due to %20 and ()

Comment: try setting `/system/application/config/config.php` configure this variable: `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\=';`

Comment: I recommend you create slug for your `college_name` and use that slug to generate url

Comment: how can I use slug with A%20B%20%20C(engineering)

Comment: add a field `slug` in your database where the data will be saved by removing all the special characters so the slug will look like `Annai-Mira-College-of-Engineering-and‌​-Technology-Vell‌​ore-engineering` and while you use query use the slug. and also use slug in your link like this `<a href='" . base_url() . "test/college/".$row['slug']."' id='coll'>" . $row['college_name'] . "</a>`. see this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305786/using-slugs-in-codeigniter)